# doctrine add count result from oneToMany to selected object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables, customer and order (oneToMany). I need select all customers(as object) and add to customer object orderTotal field. I created query like this:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
->select('c as customer', 'COUNT(o.id) as totalOrders')
->join('c.orders', 'o')
->groupBy('c.id')
->getQuery()->getResult();
```

but doctrine return me:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "customer" => Customer {#748 ▶}
    "totalOrders" => "49"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "customer" => Customer {#777 ▶}
    "totalOrders" => "50"
  ]
]
```

How change this query and move "totalOrders" to Customer object?

Comment: If only you add `getTotalOrders()` method to `Customer` class and make it returning `$this->orders->count()`. But bare in mind that this will do LAZY fetch, i.e. for every returned customer you'll get one extra `COUNT` query from the database.

Comment: That's why i need to avoid extra query for each customer and looking for other solution. Additionally in project is used datagrid library and i can't write raw query

Comment: What do you mean by "move `totalOrders` to `Customer` object"? Your `Customer` class has a `totalOrders` field? If you only need this field to be populated when you execute this specific query, why not handle the mixed result in your repository method and return the processed result set instead of the direct result of the doctrine query?